# Name app is app-debug Android android:debug =true

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. My app name is app-debug. Will it automatically set Android:debuggable =true? If I rename app , will it help?

Answer (score 1):

No, the name of your app does not affect anything other than what's displayed in the settings and other places where your app's name is shown.

It won't set `android:debuggable`, or anything else, no matter what you set the name to.

Comment: I have set Android:debuggable= false in manifest,  but Samsung store galaxy moderators sending that set this  . Is there any other place where debuggable is set too ?